# Executing Mathematica script from inside SQL Server

Tags: scripting, sql

Does anyone have experience in calling *Mathematica* from inside SQL Server to do calculations? For example, how can I make a Procedure that uses *Mathematica*? Or a job that runs some *Mathematica* script?

I saw [this post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Dec/msg00359.html) on MathGroup, but it's a little bit confusing to me. Is there an easy way?

Being more specific, I would like to execute (from inside SQL Server) a *Mathematica* script. The script works using `MathKernel -script myFile.m` but I don't know how to make SQL call it. The Mathematica is installed in another server, in the same local web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to solve this problem in SQL Sever. I used `PsExec` together with `xp_Cmdshell` to do the job. You have to install the `PsExec` in Windows in the `system32` directory of the server machine. You can find the installer [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). After that, I created this procedure, that can execute a file in a remote server:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MAT_EXEC_SCRIPT]
    @scriptName [varchar](1000)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS

BEGIN

    Declare @command varchar(1000)  
    set @command='PsExec \\192.168.0.59 -u domain\login -p password -d  C:\Rotinas\' + @scriptName 
    Exec Master..xp_Cmdshell @command

END
```

and this test bat file in the `Rotina` folder, called `exec.bat`:

```
::Test bat file to call Mathematica Scripts
@echo off
setlocal
PATH = C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0;%PATH%
start MathKernel -script "C:\Scripts\mathScript00_Test.m"
endlocal
```

Now I can execute the procedure as: `EXEC MAT_EXEC_SCRIPT 'exec.bat'`
This will call the `bat` file, which then calls the *Mathematica* script.
You can avoid this `bat` file if you want, but I prefer to keep it separated, with the intermediate `bat` file, so as to be better organized.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to run a block of Mathematica code then this questions seems to 
be equivalent to, How do I run an operating system command/script from SQL?

Using the operating system command line invocation `MathKernel -script myFile.m` you can call your Mathematica script by whichever mechanism your version of SQL supports for accessing OS commands.

Your script can return data using `SQLExecute` or by writing to an external CSV file and have SQL import it.

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL, this is done with `system 'MathKernel -script myFile.m'`, but it [only works in Unix](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-commands.html).